# Java: What are the basic/most essential JUnit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

**Question**

What are the basic/most essential JUnit test?  Is there a best practice or recipe, that would be ideal for someone just getting into TDD/Unit Testing?

**Background**

I'm interested in TDD & unit test.  Attempting to better understand it & how to use it.  I've been working through some examples & they have been a lot of help.  I'm currently trying to transition unit testing into my own work & am looking for the shallow-end of the pool, the basics, the essentials.

My question is stated above and I have an example below of an app I will try to implement some test in.  If you also know of any resources that you think are great for beginners looking to understand the when & why of test, please share.

**Example**

I've include 3 Java classes(Card, Deck, Wallet) that I'm interested in test.  Additionally, Ive included 3 Java test classes(CardTest, DeckTest, WalletTest) which are essentially empty, except for package, imports, class, and the commented-out methods I am thinking about testing.  If you could provide me with some examples that would be very helpful.

**Card**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Card {
    private String rank;
    private String suit;
    private int rankInt;

    // TODO: remove this if actually never used
    private int suitInt;

    //four argument constructor initializes Cards rank and suit (stings and ints)
    public Card(String rank, String suit, int rankInt, int suitInt) {
        super();
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rankInt = rankInt;
        this.suitInt = suitInt;
    }

    //getter method to return the rank value
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    //getter method to return the suit value
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    //setter method to initialize the suit
    public int getRankInt() {
        return rankInt;
    }

    //return String representation of Card object
    public String toString() {
        return rank + " : " + suit;
    }
}
```

**Deck**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/10/2015.
 */
public class Deck {
    private final String rank[] = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King", "Ace"};
    private final String suits[]={"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};

    private final int rankInt[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    private final int suitsInt[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    private Card deck[];
    private final int MAX = 52;
    private Random randNum;

    //makes the deck, constructor - no arguments
    public Deck() {
        deck = new Card[MAX];

        //uses calendar object to get time stamp
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long seed = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        randNum = new Random(seed); // random generated using time seed

        // uses modulus operator
        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++ ){
            deck[i] = new Card( rank[i % 13], suits[i / 13], rankInt[i % 13], suitsInt[i / 13]);
        }
    }

    //shuffles the deck
    public void shuffle(){

        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++ ){
            int j = randNum.nextInt(MAX);
            Card c = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = c;
        }
    }

    //returns the individual card in the deck
    public Card getCard(int index){
        return deck[index];
    }

    //returns rankInt from the deck object at the given index value
    public int getRankInt(int index) {
        return rankInt[index];
    }

}
```

**Wallet**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams.game;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class Wallet {
    private double balance;
    /**
     * default Wallet constructor
     */
    public Wallet() {
        setRandomStartingBalance(50.0, 500.0);
    }

    private void setRandomStartingBalance(double minimum, double maximum) {
        Random random = new Random();
        double randomStartingBalance = minimum + (maximum - minimum) * random.nextDouble();
        balance = randomStartingBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deductFromBalance(double price) {
        this.balance = balance - price;
    }
}
```

**CardTest**

package com.craigreedwilliams;

```
/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class CardTest {

//    public String getRank() {
//        return rank;
//    }

//    public String getSuit() {
//        return suit;
//    }

//    public int getRankInt() {
//        return rankInt;
//    }

//    //return String representation of Card object
//    public String toString() {
//        return rank + " : " + suit;
//    }
}
```

**DeckTest**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams;

import com.craigreedwilliams.game.Card;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class DeckTest {


//    public void shuffle(){
//        for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++ ){
//            int j = randNum.nextInt(MAX);
//            Card c = deck[i];
//            deck[i] = deck[j];
//            deck[j] = c;
//        }
//    }


//    public Card getCard(int index){
//        return deck[index];
//    }


//    public int getRankInt(int index) {
//        return rankInt[index];
//    }

}
```

**Wallet Test**

```
package com.craigreedwilliams;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Random;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by Reed on 7/11/2015.
 */
public class WalletTest {

//    private void setRandomStartingBalance(double minimum, double maximum) {
//        Random random = new Random();
//        double randomStartingBalance = minimum + (maximum - minimum) * random.nextDouble();
//        balance = randomStartingBalance;
//    }

//    public double getBalance() {
//        return balance;
//    }

//    public void deductFromBalance(double price) {
//        this.balance = balance - price;
//    }


}
```

Comment: A comment on your code: You may want to implement the `Rank`s and `Suit`s as enums. To the "basic tests"... all tests are equally important. A bug is a bug. No matter how small, it may cause havoc. That is the reason code coverage tools exist. If you begin Test Driven Developments, you start by defining certain contracts, e.g. "One cannot deposite a negative amount of money out of a wallet". Those tests are indepentent from your implementation. Later on, you may check with a code-coverate tool, which lines are tested and which are not and desing new tests to improve test coverage.

Comment: @Turing85 `all tests are equally important. A bug is a bug.` This is not true. A bug which loses data or blocks use of the software is far more important than a bug which displays data incorrectly.

Comment: @MartinCarney that depends. Imagine you switch around some outputs in your view of a medical application and because of this bug, someone does not get an organ he/she needs. You can check for logical bugs within your code, but if the user using the application has to make decisions based on your view, this bug(s) may be even more fatal.

Comment: The book [http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) is very useful for learning TDD.

Comment: @Turing85 Good counter-example. That sort of worst-case scenario is exactly why I will probably never work on health-related software.